# Как сделать , чтобы после нажатия на крестик(закрыть приложение), выскакивал MessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt

Вот про логику, как сделать сам MessageBox , я знаю. Впихиваю код в деструктор:

```
L_9_1K::~L_9_1K()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.show();
    msgBox.setText("Cохранить перед выходом?");
    msgBox.addButton(QWidget::tr("OК"), QMessageBox::RejectRole);
    msgBox.addButton(QWidget::tr("отменить"), QMessageBox::RejectRole); 
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    int res = msgBox.exec();
    if (res == QWidget::tr("OК"))
            saveSettings(); //сохраняет настройки приложения
            delete ui;
    if (res == QWidget::tr("Отменить"))
        delete ui;
}`
```

Подскажите пожалуйста , где ошибка?

Comment: все верно, только не в деструктор, а в `closeEvent`

Comment: а ещё `QMessageBox` создаёшь/получаешь результат неправильно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваш класс произведён от QDialog, то надо этот код вставлять в переопределённую функцию reject(), если от QWidget то в closeEvent()